# Drupal Search API Query

Tags: search, drupal-7

How to customize search api query? 
I have already added index from backend also added server.

By following this link but didn't get any solution.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search-results.tpl.php/7.

Comment: whish version of drupal  ?

Comment: i have use drupal 7

Comment: could this help you ; http://enzolutions.com/articles/2015/06/10/how-to-customize-a-search-api-filters-in-drupal-7/

Comment: i follow above link but i don't know where to add above code in which file
iwant to add image in my search result  i get result three field product title, code, and meta description can you please help me thank you